# How to get friendly url programmatically for a particular page url, Sharepoint 2013

Tags: navigation, term-store, variations, multilingual

So i'm missing a thing here.
My site collection is configured with variations.
I'm doing a language switch webpart, but the problem is 
How to find the friendly url for a page.

For more info please see:

```
    protected void lnkItalian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem))
            {
                PublishingPage page = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem);
                StringCollection peerUrls = page.VariationPageUrls;
                string url = "";
                foreach (var peerUrl in peerUrls)
                {
                    if (peerUrl.Contains("it-it"))
                    {
                       this.Page.Response.Redirect(peerUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This way I'm redirecting user to the original url, not the friendly one. How to grab the friendly url?

Answer (score 1):

To get the peer page of the page that you are currently in Use the below method:-

```
 ReadOnlyCollection<VariationLabel> spawnedLabels = Variations.Current.UserAccessibleLabels;

            foreach (VariationLabel label in spawnedLabels)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!currentUrl.StartsWith(label.TopWebUrl, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        string url = Variations.GetPeerUrl(SPContext.Current.Web, currentUrl, label.Title);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogVerbose(ex.Message);
                }
```

Hope this helps